# How to fix "required parameter name not set" in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, boto3

I am having a problem adding amazon S3 in my Django app, and the server keeps returning "value error required parameter name not set".please I need help because I am about to quit.again take a look at the traceback url.please  help me I am king of frustrated right now because of this.

```
 ValueError at /app/
 Required parameter name not set
      Request Method:   GET
      Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/
      Django Version:   2.0.13
      Exception Type:   ValueError
      Exception Value:  
      Required parameter name not set
      Exception Location:   C:\Python34\lib\site- 
      packages\boto3\resources\base.py in __init__, line 119
      Python Executable:    C:\Python34\python.exe
      Python Version:   3.4.4
      Python Path:  
      ['C:\\Users\\Mustapha\\Desktop\\Myfirstapp',
       'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',
       'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
       'C:\\Python34\\lib',
       'C:\\Python34',
       'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
        Server time:    Wed, 11 Sep 2019 01:20:16 +0000
```

templates

required parameter not set:

```
 <img src="{{Blogger.image.url}}"  width="70" height="70"  class="c" />
```

traceback:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 398, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[11/Sep/2019 12:24:51] "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 64131)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 398, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 86, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 617, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 344, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 673, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 154, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

---

Comment: Please share the *full* traceback, together with the relevant URL, etc.

Comment: Are you sure that the Request Method should be `GET`, and not `POST`?

Comment: **@WillemVanOnsem**  yea please take a loot at the traceback, thanks in advance.